# How do I change the number format for the horizontal axis labels in a histogram?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to change the number format of the horizontal axis labels of a histogram. Some tutorials mention that this should work, e.g.

- [New chart text and number formatting options in Sheets](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/07/customize-chart-text-numbers-google-sheets.html)
- [How To☝️ Change Axis Scales In A Google Sheets Chart](https://spreadsheetdaddy.com/google-sheets/axis-scale)

However, the option to change the number format seems to be gone, see the following screenshot:
[image: Sceenshot]

Is it possible that Google removed that feature? And/or can this be done differently?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, in order for me to see this setting, I had to click the number on the axis. Only then did the setting to change the number format. From there, you can choose to use the format of the source data or set your own.

Comment: That is quite strange. I do see the number format setting when I click on tick labels for the vertical axis, but not for the tick labels on the horizontal axis.